# How to arrange a wordpress htaccess to access a directory with a complete web inside

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm failing in edit a .htaccess file.
I created a complete website in a php slim framework (let's call it website S).
My client have a wordpress website (let's call it website W) that will have links toward my website S.
I copied all the files of my website S inside a directory of the root directory of the website W.

My idea is to change the follow htaccess (created by wordpress) to allow public access to the directory without creating any problem to move inside website S.

**First .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !wc-api [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.pe$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.pe
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.pe/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Then, I guess I could use inside the directory where the website S would be, the typical htaccess that works properly for it.
*Edited* I added the structure of the website S. The index.php is inside a public directory there.

**Second .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
  
  RewriteBase /
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I try different ways but, or get the message
"Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."
Or get inside but the website W stop working.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the URLs for your "slim" website include the subdirectory where the site is contained? Are there multiple domains pointing at this site? Or is `website.pe` the only one?

Comment: The URLs from the slim only point inside the subdirectory where the slim website S is contained.
There are not multiple domains, only website.pe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
>   RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
>   
>   RewriteBase /
>   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

In the config you've posted you would just need to remove the `RewriteBase /` directive from the second `.htaccess` file in the "slim" subdirectory. This is causing requests to your slim website to be routed back through the WordPress site in the document root (which would presumably result in a 404).

> My idea is to change the follow htaccess (created by wordpress) to allow public access to the directory without creating any problem to move inside website S

You shouldn't need to touch the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the document root. This already allows you to access website S.

By default, the `.htaccess` file (or rather, the mod_rewrite directives) in the slim subdirectory is going to completely override the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the root.

Consequently, you'll need to repeat the HTTP to HTTPS redirect in the slim subdirectory (with a difference<sup>***1**</sup>), before the existing directives. Presumably, the intention is to also redirect www to non-www? Although your current redirect (in the root `.htaccess` file) is not doing this properly.

For example, at the top of your second `.htaccess` file in the slim directory add the following:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(website\.pe) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

<sup>***1**</sup> Note the use of the `REQUEST_URI` variable instead of the `$1` backreference as used in the root `.htaccess` file. This is necessary when used in the subdirectory, otherwise, the subdirectory will be omitted from the redirected URL.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

---

**UPDATE:**

> But I can't make the website S to run because inside the website S directory exist a public subdirectory with the index.php, arranged like this:
>
> ```
> website.pe/ (website W wordpress)
> -slimdirectory/ (website S slim)
> --vendor/
> --public/
> ---css/
> ---fonts/
> ---images/
> ---js/
> ---index.php
> --bootstrap/
> ---app.php
> --etc..
> ```

This is a rather important bit of information missing from your initial question. I assume that the `public` subdirectory is *not* part of the visible URL, in which case your second `.htaccess` file in the slim subdirectory (the parent directory of `public`) should be something like this instead:

```
# /slimdirectory/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(website\.pe) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Calculate base directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Slim front-controller
RewriteRule ^public/index\.php - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
```

The `QSA` flag is not required.

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, now is working. 
I have new problems with the routes of the Slim configuration, but the directory is accessible as expected. Thanks indeed.

Comment: Cool... I will do that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes MrWhite, I delete in the second .htaccess the `RewriteBase /` and now I can access a simple index.html in the directory where the slim website is that I used for testing.

But I can't make the website S to run because inside the website S directory exist a public subdirectory with the index.php, arranged like this:

```
website.pe/ (website W wordpress)
-slimdirectory/ (website S slim)
--.htacess
--vendor/
--public/
---css/
---fonts/
---images/
---js/
---index.php
--bootstrap/
---app.php
--etc..
```

I am new to htaccess and don't understand how one htaccess overwrite the other one, so if I use something like you told me in my second htaccess only like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www
   RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(website\.pe) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

That should work... but still not

Comment: "because inside the website S directory exist a public subdirectory with the index.php" - Why didn't you add this information to your question? (You need to edit your question to add this information). This would also mean that "the typical htaccess that works properly for it" cannot possibly work properly for it!? Is `/public` part of the visible URL? (I assume not)

Comment: I assume the "slim" `.htaccess` file is located at `/slimdirectory/.htaccess` and there is no `index.php` file located directly inside the `/slimdirectory`? I'm assuming the `BASE` environment variable is required by the slim framework? (You've omitted this in your updated `.htaccess` file?) You're updated `.htaccess` file would still route all requests to a non-existent `index.php` file in the slim subdirectory. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, MrWhite, you are right. I was in the idea of supposing facts instead of explicit them, my mistake.  When I said work propertly, for me means that "if not" was inside the wordpress website. I was assuming wrong and gave wrong information.

I will edit my question more accurately.